# how to show images inside html text using textview

Tags: android, textview

Guys I have a textview that show a html text, and it has image tag inside. 
I want to show the image using imageGetter but it just show a little blue box.
I've been working with this problem for days. so please help me with this.

my current code is this

```
  TextView textD = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.body);
  textD.setText(Html.fromHtml(Body, imgGetter, null));
  textD.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());

 private ImageGetter imgGetter = new ImageGetter() {

        public Drawable getDrawable(String source) {


          try{
           InputStream is = (InputStream) new URL(source).getContent();
           Drawable d = Drawable.createFromStream(is, "src name");
           return d;
          }catch (Exception e){
           Log.d("image", imageSource, e);
           return null;
          }

        }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

The reference says:

> The setBounds(Rect) method must be called to tell the Drawable where
>   it is drawn and how large it should be. All Drawables should respect
>   the requested size, often simply by scaling their imagery. A client
>   can find the preferred size for some Drawables with the
>   getIntrinsicHeight() and getIntrinsicWidth() methods.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/Drawable.html

So try this:

```
d.setBounds(0,0,d.getIntrinsicWidth(),d.getIntrinsicHeight());
```

Itt will work!

Comment: Setting the bounds is, in fact, absolutely necessary. @Rahadyanteja - please accept this as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(this); 
TextView question = new TextView(this);
question.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)); 
question.setTextSize(20);
question.setTextColor(Color.WHITE); 
CharSequence text2 = Html.fromHtml(qstnText, new Html.ImageGetter(){ 
    public Drawable getDrawable(String source){ 
        System.out.println("Source:::"+source); 
        String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() +source; 
        File f = new File(path); 
        // Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(f.getAbsolutePath()); 
        Drawable bmp = Drawable.createFromPath(f.getAbsolutePath());
        bmp.setBounds(0,0,50,50); return bmp; 
    } 
}, null); 
question.setText(text2); 
ll.addView(question);
```

Its works fine for me... Try it